# showing <div> inside :before element

Tags: html, css

Using `:before` to add an icon font to a div for a css3 hover state. I want to include a div inside the `<a>` tag to allow both to serve as a link:

```
<a href="#set-4" class="column product hi-icon product-icon"><div>Product</div></a>
```

css:

```
.product-icon:before {
    content: "\e601";
    margin-top: "-4px";
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the title `div` to display.

I have constructed a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyyOzM?editors=110) to display the problem. Can anyone point me towards the solution? Thanks very much!

Comment: It would be nice if you showed enough of your code in the question so that anyone finding this in the future will be able to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Lance. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` is inheriting a `font-size` of `0` from `.hi-icon`. Remove that, and it shows below the circle.

Answer (score 0):

First: you can't add `html` via :before and :after pseudoclasses.

Second: both :before and :after adds it's contents *outside* of referenced element, not *inside*. So, even if you'd might use :before/:after for `html` insertion, you'd ended with `<div><a ...>Product</a></div>`, not `<a ...><div>Product</div></a>`.

If you really need auto-wrap contents of `a` with `div`, just use jQuery for that:

```
$('.product-icon').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
});
```